# How to update item in array using react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Could you please tell me how to update item in array using react? I make a dynamic list using `add` button. In generated Item I have two button `update` and `delete`.
On click of update button I change the text of add button to `update` and fill the selected value in input field. Now when I click update button  I want to update the selected item.

Here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/bpSGPLLoDZcofV4DYxPe?p=preview

```
  addName() {
    if (this.state.username !== '') {
        if (this.state.btnText === 'add') {
            this.props.add(this.state.username)
        } else if (this.state.btnText === 'update') {
            this.props.updateItem(this.state.username)
        }
        this.setState({
            username: '',
            btnText: 'add'
        })
    }
}
delete(item) {
    this.props.deleteItem(item)
}
  update(item){
     this.setState({
      username : item,
      btnText:'update'
    })
  }
```

Comment: your code in plunkr doesn't contain any update button

Comment: please fill input value and click `add` button .then you see update button

Comment: Nope its not there in the plunkr link that you provided.

Comment: ohh by mistake https://plnkr.co/edit/bpSGPLLoDZcofV4DYxPe?p=preview

Comment: Now you can see this .update button is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the updated item name and the indexof the item to the update case in the reducer. Then just use splice to update the new value

Updated the plunkr. Check it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3FOnba9vdQO8IV2KJy3F?p=preview)

```
case 'UPDATE_ITEM':
        let newList = state.slice()
        newList.splice(action.payload.index, 1, action.payload.item)
        return newList;
```